# Material UI: Center CardContent within Card componenet

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to horizontally AND vertically center the CardContent within a Card component using Material UI.

This is what I have:

```
const styles = {
  card: {
    maxWidth: 120,
    minHeight: 120,
    maxHeight: 120,
  },
}
```

...

```
<Card className={this.props.classes.card}>
  <CardContent>
    <Grid container justify="center">
      <Grid item xs={12} style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
        <Typography gutterBottom align="center" variant="title">
          Markedup123 Plan
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </CardContent>
</Card>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

How do I center the CardContent horizontally and vertically?

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pw90op914q

Comment: why did you delete my answer and your previous question ? I think I answered the question and you are using my example and forked version of my answer to show your working examples.

Comment: Because I wasn't getting any answers - and your answer was nice but it didn't really fully solve the problem. Do you have a working solution where CardContent is vertically and horizontally centered?